# How can I return additional (i.e. more than just field=>error message) validation information from custom validation code to the Controller or View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am looking for a way to return the following information from my custom validation code:

```
public enum ValidationErrorTypeFlags
{
    Error_Input = 1 << 0,               // a "field specific" error which is checked both clientside and serverside 
    Error_Input_ServerSide = 1 << 1,    // a "field specific" error which can only be checked serverside
    Error_General = 1 << 2              // serverside general error
}
```

Inside the validation code (either an IValidatableObject or a ValidationAttribute), when I detect an error, I would like to be able to associate one of the above error types with the ValidationResult.

Then I want to be able to iterate through the validation errors in either the Controller or the View and distinguish between these error types.

I'm currently using MVC 3 (happy to upgrade to 4).

NB:

- ModelState does not preserve ValidationResults AFAIK - you can only access errors in ViewData.ModelState.Values.Items[x].Errors - and these have been converted to System.Web.Mvc.ModelError
- It seems that MVC validation only allows you to access [key, 'error message'] type validation results after validation has completed.

The hack I'm using at present is to decorate the error message inside the custom validation code:

```
var field = new[] { validationContext.DisplayName };
return new ValidationResult("+Invalid format - use yyyy-mm-dd", field);
```

And then look for error messages which start with +,-,* in the controller.

Comment: I've counted quite a few different places in MVC3 where ModelValidationError is converted to ModelState so I don't think there's an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

From custom validation code (no idea how to accomplish from built-in ones) you can do that by creating a custom `ValidationResult` class by inheriting from the base and return from your custom validation attributes.

```
public class CustomValidationResult: ValidationResult
{
   // additional properties
}
```

Then from the controller you can cast and check if the validation result is your custom type and act accordingly.

**Update:**

The above idea don't work because the `ValidationResult` class is in DataAnnotations assembly and they are converted into `ModelValidationResult` and that's all we can access in MVC.

It seems passing extra information from the data annotation validations to the MVC looks like not quite easy!

I was going through the source code and found that it is the `ValidatableObjectAdapter` that converts the `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` into `IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult>`. I don't see much benefit on extending this class but we can easily create a custom `ValidatableObjectAdapter` by implementing the `ModelValidator`and duplicating the `Validate` code.

We have to create a custom `ModelValidationResult` and custom `ValidationResult`(it is this custom `ValidationResult` we will b returning from validations) and in the `ConvertResults` method we can put our conversion code that takes care of the additional information.

```
public class CustomValidatableObjectAdapter : ModelValidator
{
    public CustomValidatableObjectAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
      : base(metadata, context)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
    {
      object model = Metadata.Model;
      if (model == null)
      {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
      }

      IValidatableObject validatable = model as IValidatableObject;
      if (validatable == null)
      {
        throw new Exception("model is of not type validatable");
      }

      ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(validatable, null, null);

      return ConvertResults(validatable.Validate(validationContext));
    }

    private IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> ConvertResults(IEnumerable<ValidationResult> results)
    {
      foreach (ValidationResult result in results)
      {
        // iterate the ValidationResult enumeration and cast each into CustomValidationResult
        // and conver them into enumeration of CustomModelValidationResult.
      }
    }
}
```

Finally we have to tell the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` use this our `CustomValidatableObjectAdapter` in the `Application_Start` event of Global.asax.cs.

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterDefaultValidatableObjectAdapterFactory((metadata, context) => new CustomValidatableObjectAdapter(metadata, context));
```

So you have to create a custom `ValidationResult`, custom `ModelValidationResult` and a custom `ValidatableObjectAdapter`.

I haven't tested this but I hope this will work. I may suggest a better and easier solution than this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this previously but could not find a variable that is accessible in the controller which I could cast. Could you point me in the right direction? I've tried ModelState but as mentioned this only has ModelError's not ValidationResults.

Comment: Just read a post on your blog http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/model_validation_in_asp_net_mvc. The IClientValidatable is a good tip - it has some similar goals to what I'm attempting.

Comment: @Illan somehow i found a way.. i'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: @Ilan I updated the answer and looks like it's not that easy!

Comment: thanks for doing all of this. I'll try it out tomorrow and update here. MVC clearly hasn't been designed with complex ValidationResults in mind. Rather than repeating stuff which the framework does - and which will change with the next update - I may just stick with the hack I've got - at least it's simple. Which MVC source did you look at btw? 3 or 4?